# extending scala base Vector constructor

Tags: scala, class, constructor

Just learning scala and having trouble extending the base vector class -- I looked around for the constructor signatures but couldn't parse the docs.  Can anyone tell me the correct way to write the code below? (no error checking necessary)

```
class VD(x: Vector) extends Vector(x){
       def +(that: VD) = that.foreach{ case (e,i) => that(i)+this(i)}
       }
<console>:12: error: constructor Vector in class Vector cannot be accessed in object $iw
```

Thanks!

Comment: When [perusing the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Vector$), if you need more detail you can click through to the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala#L1).  The link is near the top of each page.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and guidance, they are a big help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is with a ["rich wrapper"](http://jonathanwarden.com/2013/07/19/retroactive-extension-in-scala-adaptors-views-type-classes-and-structural-types/), which Scala itself uses extensively to extend basic types. An implicit conversion is done from the Scala `Vector` to your own class (here called `MyVector`) which contains the method you want to add. That method then returns a plain `Vector`.

```
class MyVector[T](val underlying: Vector[T]) {
  def +(that: Vector[T])(implicit x: scala.math.Numeric[T]): Vector[T] = {
    import x._
    underlying.zip(that).map {
      case (a,b) => a + b
    }
  }
}

object MyVector {
  implicit def toMyVector[T](that: Vector[T]): MyVector[T] = new MyVector(that)
}

import MyVector._

val a = Vector(1, 2, 3)
val b = Vector(4, 5, 6)
val c = a + b
```

Output:

```
a: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
b: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(4, 5, 6)
c: Vector[Int] = Vector(5, 7, 9)
```

Also uses some [magic](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/6021.html) to allow addition of the generic parameter `T` in the `+` function.

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, another optimization is to use an [implicit class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) and omit the companion object. Yet another optimization is to make it a [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

```
object VectorStuff {
  implicit class MyVector[T](val underlying: Vector[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def +(that: Vector[T])(implicit x: scala.math.Numeric[T]): Vector[T] = {
      import x._
      underlying.zip(that).map {
        case (a, b) => a + b
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then `import VectorStuff._` wherever you need it.

Comment: "Implicit class" syntax helps to reduce boilerplate. So, `implicit class MyVector[T](val underlying: Vector[T]) { ...`.

Answer (score 1):

A Vector is a final class. It cannot be extended.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your source?

Comment: From the source (linked to by @jwvh) `final class Vector[+A] private[immutable] ...`